# Search by keyword in Saferproducts.gov API?

Tags: odata

I am trying to search for a Report on the basis of keyword from safeproducts api (http://www.saferproducts.gov/webapi/Cpsc.Cpsrms.Web.Api.svc) like they provide search functionality on their site at http://www.saferproducts.gov/Search/default.aspx

But I could not find any way to search it. Their API is in OData format which I have never used before so I am guessing its may be my lack of knowledge of how to query OData based service or they just don't provide any search method in their web service.

Can any one plz confirm my understanding is correct ?

Thanks,
Khan

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `$filter` to have the search. 
But if the service is based on OData V3, the Uri should be:

```
http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$filter=substringof('Alfreds', CompanyName)
```

You can reference [OData V3 URL Conventions](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/url-conventions/)

If the service is based on OData V4, the Uri should be:

```
http://host/service/Customers?$filter=contains(CompanyName,'Alfreds')
```

You can reference [OData V4 URL Conventions](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.html)

By the way, you can access `http://www.saferproducts.gov/webapi/Cpsc.Cpsrms.Web.Api.svc/$metadata`
to identify the service version. If you have "`m:DataServiceVersion="3.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0"`" on the top of the page, the service should be based on OData V3. If there is no such line, then the service should be based on OData V4.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$filter` query option combined with the `Contains` Function defined in the OData protocol.

```
http://host/service/Customers?$filter=contains(CompanyName,'Alfreds')
```

(Example from OData Documentation: all customers with a CompanyName that contains 'Alfreds')

Concern the [OData documentation](http://www.odata.org/documentation/) for further details.